# how to remove a header from URLConnection

Tags: java, post, content-type, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I am talking to a file upload service that accepts post data, not form data. By default, java's `HttpURLConnection` sets the `Content-Type` header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. this is obviously wrong if i'm posting pure data.

I (the client) don't know the content type. I don't want the `Content-Type` header set at all. the service has a feature where it will guess at the content type (based on the file name, reading some data from the file, etc).

How do I unset a header? There's no remove header, and setting it to `null` doesn't change the value and setting it to the empty string results in the header being set with no value.

Comment: Did you find any way for this?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested this approach but you can try this:

Extend HttpURLConnection and try by overriding its getContentHandler() and setContentHandler(...) methods. Most probably this should work as, you will take a look at code of getContentHandler().

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/quickstart.html) instead of URLConnection

Use fluent [Request](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/fluent-hc/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/fluent/Request.html) to generate your request

use removeHeader()

Comment: not an option, as i need to produce a library that can run on android and plain JSE. the problem w/ android is that it bundles a 4.x version of httpclient that doesn't match with any standalone released version. if you try to bundle a specific version of httpclient, you get conflicts.

Comment: I try to implement a bot which using Google Image Search (not using custom search), and Google Image Search seems does not send `Content-Type` and `Content-Length` headers, so I have same issue. And HttpClient of apache httpcomponents does not fit my case too: HttpClient does not support SOCKS proxy (need a tweak, and I don't like that).

Answer (score 0):

I just accomplished this by setting the header to null.

```
connection.setRequestProperty(MY_HEADER, null);
```

Comment: For User-Agent, that just additionally writes `User-Agent` with no colon or value, and then writes the original value nevertheless. Not ideal.

Answer (score -1):

What do you mean "i don't want the Content-Type header to set at all"?

The browser (or other http client) sends your post request to the server, so it has to inform the server which way it encoded the parameters.

If the Content-Type header is not set, on the server side you (= your server) won't be able to understand how to parse the received data.

If you didn't set Content-Type, the default value will be used.

You browser (or other http client) MUST do two things:

1. Send key/value pairs.
2. Inform the server how the key/value pairs were encoded.

So, it is impossible to completely get rid of this header.

Comment: i'm not sending parameters. it's file upload. i'm posting binary data. the service saves the binary content as-is. the only reason it needs content type is to set meta data for the file.

Comment: If you upload a image file to Google Image Search, the browser does not send `Content-Type` header, and `Content-Length` header is missing too.